# How to do exception handling in my code

Tags: c#, parsing, matrix, exception, try-catch

I just learned about exception handling. So, I am still getting use to it. I know how to do the basic exception handling like entering in a correct value for division and having it throw a DividebyZeroException if a incorrect value is entered.

**But I need help some help on doing the following:**

Create an exception handling to throw an error if

1) The number of integer in each row are not equal to each other for example: Matrix  = [ 3 4; 9 8 1] *should be*: matrix  = [ 3 4 2; 9 8 1]

2) the semicolon ";" that I use as a separator is replace by an invalid character such as: matrix  = [ 3 4 2 # 9 8 1]

**This is my code:**

this is from my main in which I create the string.

```
string text = "A = [8 5 5 4; 2 6 5 3; 8 5 2 6]";
```

this is my class

```
public string[,] Matrix(string text)
{
    try
    {
        char[] splitOne = { '[', ']' };
        char[] splitTwo = { ';' };
        char[] splitThree = { ' ' };
        words = text.Split(splitOne)[1]
                               .Split(splitTwo, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                               .Select(x => x.Split(splitThree, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                               .ToArray();
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try entering a correct string");

    }


    string[,] matrix = new string[words.Length, words[0].Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < words[i].Length; ++j)
        {
            matrix[i, j] = words[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", matrix[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

**How would I make the try and catch work? This is a basic general catch all but how would I make it work with my following requirements as well. Right now it is not outputting my message.**

Comment: Currently your not doing anything inside the `try` that could fail.   add this to the try `int x = int.Parse("Designed To Fail");`  and it should then crash on that (because you can't parse that string to an int) and output your code in the catch.  Edit:  Try catch will only catch system exceptions,  not logic errors that don't cause system exceptions.  The exception to this being if you `throw exception`  for example  `if(words.Length < 2){ throw new Exception("too few values here"); }`

Comment: I thought that if I change my matrix string to this:  matrix = [ 3 4 2 # 9 8 1] it would fail the try portion but it doesn't.

Comment: That's correct,  it just trys to split on the ;  doesn't see any ; and moves on.   There's no actual fail,  it would be like trying to do `String.replace('x', 'y')` when you don't have any x's   it runs,  does nothing,  but doesn't fail.   your code is the same.  it runs,  doesn't do what you want,  but it also doesn't fail,   this is because it's a logic error on your part,  not a system exception,   what you could do is something like  `if(text.IndexOf('#') > 0){ throw new Execption("# found, please use ;");`

Comment: ohh. I see now. That clears that part up for me. but does that part of the code go into the try-catch?

Comment: yes you can put it in the try catch. what it will do, is if it finds a # in the string, then it will throw the error and force the catch to occur.   Just be aware that it will then continue on,  it will NOT do the try again,  this means that if it does catch,  everything below the try/catch in your code will still try to execute and probably crash your program on null/empty arrays. (out of bounds errors)

Comment: In addition:  For your code above,  i would do the validation of the text parameter in the calling method.   something like `If(myInput.indexof("#")>0) { console.writeline("Please input the correct code") }`   put that in some kind of loop, that breaks once the input has been validated as correct,  then call `Matrix(myInput)`

Comment: If you are throwing Exceptions in the same scope as the try catch i would consider it a anti pattern.

Comment: I see. 1) So, I put it in the try portion and there's a red underline on Exception. 2) so how will I avoid the lower portion from executing, because I don't think I want to move it into the try portion. Do I?

Comment: If there is a red underline under Exception,  then it cannot find the class,   just check that you spelled it correctly,  if you copy and pasted then you took my spelling mistake with you (Sorry!)  Exception is the correct spelling and it should work fine. Edit:  part 2!  you have 2 options,  1) you can put it all into the try/catch but you still have to return a value somewhere if it fails and this will be empty 2) return null in the catch. (and check for a return null in your calling method)

Comment: Ohh yes now it works! but like you said it crashes. To your post above with the validation I am only reading in a string that is hard coded. There is no user's input.

Comment: in that case,  don't put it in a loop,  but what your trying to do is input (hard coded or whatever) validation,  data cleansing.  Try catch isn't what you need to use in this case.  it's for catching things that straight up fail from a code point of view,  out of bounds exceptions,  trying to connect to a Database that doesn't exist,  etc,   the Try catch allows you to handle the fact that it failed (in the catch) without having the program throw a run time error and crash.  try catch doesn't care bout incorrect values unless it causes a code error. Eg: trying to parse a string to an int

Comment: Ohh okay. Well I am in the early beginnings of my studies of exception handlings and c#. So, this is the only thing that I learn so far. So, How would I do the requirements that I have above. I want it to throw the error message that is specific to what is wrong. So, I can't just put it all into one catch. Furthermore, if the try and catch is not used here is it possible to use a if statement? ohh one more thing so I put it in my try portion but "# found, please use ;" does not show it just display my message that I have in the catch.

Comment: to make your message show,  do this:  `catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }`    you can have multiple try catch in a method,   you can do `try {} catch{}     try{} catch {}`   each catch will only operate for it's related try.

Comment: I basically did a nested try catch -  try{  try{}catch{}  }catch{ } and added this part in the inner try                     if (text.IndexOf('#') > 0) { throw new Exception("# found, please use ;"); }
                    if (text.IndexOf('$') > 0) { throw new Exception("$ found"); }. but how do I add your part to multiple try catch?

Comment: personally i'm not a fan of nested try catch. if i see a need for that i'll generally create another method.  but there's no real reason you can't do it,   in the case of the exception,  just add it the same way.  so it will look like  `try {  try {} catch(Exception e) { console.WriteLine(e.Message); } } catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }`   Just be careful not to use it redundantly,  you need to have extra code outside the imbedded try catch that you want to run no matter what.  so   `try {  run some code; try { run some more code; }  catch {}  run other code; } catch {}`

Comment: Yes. I am starting to see problems that I could run into with it being nested  as well, but for now I am trying to make it work first then I will improve from there. So, yes I am trying your way with the output. I have a question about it. For the "e", can it be a different character for each catch(exception e)? and Now that I got that part done with the separator, do you know what is wrong with my number 1 requirement? here is the part of the code text.Split(';')[0].Replace(" ", "").Length != text.Split(';')[1].Replace(" ", "").Length -- I actually got this from the bottom answer.

Comment: it can be anything you want,  you are passing the exception into the catch as a parameter,   there are other exception types as well.  Exception is just the generic one.  `catch(Exception e) { }`    is basically the coded version of `catch(Objectoftypeexception variablename) {} `  you could have `catch(Exception myException) {}`  if you wanted,  or you could be passing through a different ExceptionType,  something like `catch(SQLException mySQLError) {}`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstanding `Exceptions`, you want to use `Exceptions` as rules for your data structure. Instead `Exceptions` is when an error occour in a method, as you are dividing with `0` in a math operation. This is a critical error, where the code does not know what to do.

For this concrete example, you should do `if` statements. Because you want to apply rules and enforce it and `Exceptions` does not fit these use cases well, if you where to implement it, you would need `if` statements to check if the string you want to apply the rules to, was well formed after your standards and after that throw an `Exception`. Moreso this makes sense if you are creating a library.

My solution to what the code should look like.

```
String text = "A = [8 5 3 4; 2 6 5 3; 8 5 2 3]";

var startIndex = text.IndexOf('[') + 1;
var length = text.IndexOf(']') - startIndex;
text = text.Substring(startIndex, length);

if(!text.Contains(";"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("malformed seperator");

    return;
}

var test = text.Split(';').Select((k, i) => new {Key = i, Value = k.Replace(" ", "").Length});


if(!test.All(x => x.Value == test.First().Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("unbalanced array");
    return;
}
```

But i think you are making your self work harder then you should, your design implies that a lot of things goes right in the string creation and using already build matrix libraries would save a lot of work here.

**EDIT**

Updated the solution to work, but i still think the design of the string matrix forces the code in a lot of directions that is unecesary.

Comment: This is simple, which is nice. However, is the second code correct?

Comment: No it doesn't misunderstood the matrix definition will update it when i get the time

Comment: Yes, I have solved it. Your help was much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: If i helped you it would be apreciated i you would accept my answer, if you solved it otherwise you should write your solution as an answer to this question :)