# Need some help on my exception handling

Tags: c#, string, parsing, matrix, exception

I want to create an exception handling to throw an error if the numbers of integers in each row are not equal to each other.

For example: Matrix = [ 3 4; 9 8 1] should be: matrix = [ 3 4 2; 9 8 1]

**This is my code:**

This is from my main, in which I create the string.

```
string text = "A = [8 5 5 4; 2 6 5 3; 8 5 2 6]";
```

This is my class:

```
public string[,] Matrix(string text)
{
        char[] splitOne = { '[', ']' };
        char[] splitTwo = { ';' };
        char[] splitThree = { ' ' };
        words = text.Split(splitOne)[1]
                               .Split(splitTwo, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                               .Select(x => x.Split(splitThree, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                               .ToArray();

                if (text.Split(';')[0].Replace(" ", " ").Length != text.Split(';')[1].Replace(" ", " ").Length)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("unbalanced matrix");
                    return null;
                }

    string[,] matrix = new string[words.Length, words[0].Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < words[i].Length; ++j)
        {
            matrix[i, j] = words[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", matrix[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

I added the if statement to do the exception handling. But it keeps on displaying the error message

> `Console.WriteLine("unbalanced matrix");`

even when the matrix is a balanced matrix. I need some help with making this part of the code work. I try changing the 0 and 1 in the two brackets to 2 and 2 and it kind of works but not really.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do exception handling in my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600810/how-to-do-exception-handling-in-my-code)

Answer (score 0):

The first two elements after `Split`: `"8 5 5 4"` and `" 2 6 5 3"`, their `Length` being `7` and `8` respectively. Replacing spaces with spaces does nothing: `Length` is still `7` and `8`. Also note that `100 3` and `1 2 3` have the same `Length`.

What you want to check is if each element of `Split(';')` which was then `Split(' ')` has the same `Length` (`4` in the first example, and `2` and `3` in my second example). You would also want to do it in a loop, because testing just first two rows does not protect you from `[1 2; 3 4; 5 6 7 8]`.

Finally, `Console.WriteLine` is not throwing an exception, which is what I suppose you should be doing in this exercise, given the wording of your task: you need `throw`. Learn more about exceptions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w8f0bss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: So, I try doing something like this :                     if (text.Split(' ')[0].Length != text.Split(' ')[1].Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("unbalanced matrix");
                        return null;
                    }     It does not work. If I take a number away from the second row it does not output my console.writeline, which I think it should

Comment: No, that won't work. The easiest way I can think of is to `Split(;)` first, then `Select` each element of the list into `Trim` and `Split(' ')`, then see if the `HashSet` of those values only has one element. (Then again, easy for me might not be easy for you. Still, check out the docs on the methods and classes I named.)

Comment: Yeah. Not easy for me. I'm still learning c# and it does not tell me this in the book I'm learning from. lol I'll still try though.

Comment: As I said, this is not the only way to do it; it's just how I'd do it. You can use `foreach` and some more logic instead of `Select` and `HashSet` to check whether each semicolon-separated element has the same number of space-separated elements. But `Trim` you should use. And book or no book - you should get used as soon as possible to checking out documentation for individual classes/methods, as it's a part and parcel of programming profession (even for people with decades of experience).

Comment: It could. It does not have to. EDIT: I just noticed, you are already doing the correct thing in your `words =` statement; now you just need to use the results there. What does `words.Select(word => word.Length)` do? And how would you make sure all of the lengths are same, and not just the first two?

Comment: does that compare the entries that were split?

Comment: No; but try it and see what it does result in.